# Can a synthesist use a different weapon than his eidolon is using?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, eidolon

As the synthesist is inside the eidolon, can the synthesist wield a different weapon from the weapon wielded by the eidolon? For example, an enemy gets adjacent to the eidolon that's armed with a longspear; can the sythesist that's inside the eidolon attack that enemy with the quaterstaff the sythesist wields?

I know that the synthesist and his eidolon can't take separate actions, but this would be *instead of* the eidolon attacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### By default, a [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist) is not *inside* his eidolon; instead, synthesist and eidolon become one

That is, after the [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist) summons his eidolon, the resulting creature is *both* the synthesist *and* his eidolon *combined* into a lone individual. The introductory description of the [summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner) archetype [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist) says

> Rather than summon an eidolon to serve by his side, the synthesist fuses his eidolon’s essence to his own. Instead of two creatures, the synthesist is a fusion of the summoner and eidolon into a single being.

Thus it's probably best *not* to imagine, for example, the synthesist, like, *floating* inside his giant [mecha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecha) eidolon's chest cavity while wielding a weapon different from that of his eidolon, and better to imagine instead the synthesist bringing forth a largely form-fitting eidolon *suit* and the synthesist/eidolon wielding whatever the synthesist himself was wielding when the eidolon was summoned.

Likewise, as you mentioned, the description of the [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist) special ability fused eidolon says, "The synthesist and eidolon cannot take separate actions." This means that if the typical synthesist's eidolon is summoned while the synthesist's wielding a quarterstaff, the synthesist/eidolon's wielding a quarterstaff, and the synthesist/eidolon must drop that quarterstaff to wield instead, for example, a longspear.

(James Jacobs says [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=298?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#14851) (and an earlier seeming contradiction is neatly resolved [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ppmy?Can-an-eidolon-take-gear-back-with-it-when#1)) that an eidolon that's given gear is thereafter summoned with that same gear, but that *doesn't* mean that the eidolon is summoned with a weapon in hand and ready to go stab some fools!)

That said, a player can't have the synthesist portion of his synthesist/eidolon attack with a quarterstaff while the eidolon portion wields a longspear anymore than a creature can have *its own skeleton* make an attack with a longspear wielded in its bony claws while it continues to wield a quarterstaff in its fleshy paws. (Unless, of course, that's one of the creature's *really awesome* special abilities.)

---

Note that the [summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner) archetype [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist) is likely the most contentious archetype ever published—for instance, one 20-page Paizo messageboard [thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mi13&page=1?One-Synthesist-Summoner-Thread-to-rule-them-all) about how the archetype works that was started in 2011 has gotten new questions as recently as Apr. 2016. Thus, if you decide to use the archetype in your home game (because it's not Pathfinder Society legal anyway), *expect* a GM to make house rules and judgment calls. These could include granting the synthesist the ability to reskin his eidolon suit in such a way that permits doing *exactly* what the question proposes. In other words, see what the GM will allow, have fun, and try to let the game run smoothly despite having picked a challenging and controversial archetype.

Comment: Thanks sounds more fare that way.  As I read your answer I thought of something. If the eidolon has extra arms evolution I could have a reach and none reach option????? (not at the same time)

Comment: @Roland Sure, but, really, all that takes is a longspear and a bite attack, for example.